# Referencing Outside Sheets in Module - Subscript out of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro such that any time a cell in column M of sheet2 is changed to "Special", the row number of that cell is copied into the first blank cell in column B of Sheet12.  Here's what I have so far, currently in Sheet2:

```
If Target.column = 13 Then

    Dim l As Integer

    With Sheet2

        For l = 3 To 1000
            If .Cells(l, 13) = "Special" Then
                Worksheets("sheet12").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = l
            End If
        Next

    End With

End If
```

Right now I'm getting a Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range for line `Worksheets("sheet12").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = l`, but I'm not sure what to change after trying several iterations with the same error.  I know that there are several other questions referring to this type of error, but I couldn't find any that helped with this specific script.

Comment: Should it be "Sheet12"? Also, I am more of a fan of range("B100000").end(xlup)

Comment: I want it to loop through column M in Sheet2, in order to make a change in Sheet12. @Lowpar

Comment: Yeha, in your code you have "sheet12" not "Sheet12", subscript out of range indicates you are not pointing to an available memory node

Comment: Oh I see, I did make that change just now (along with the previous correction), but am still receiving the same error. @Lowpar

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer the .end(xlup) approach? Does it have better performance?

Comment: because it is more robust to missing data within a column.

Comment: Is your worksheet named "Sheet12", or is that just its `CodeName` property.  (You are using the `CodeName` "Sheet2", rather than a sheet name of "Sheet2", so it seems like you might have proper names allocated to your sheets.)

Comment: You are right - I was using the code name instead of the sheet name.  Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean you were using the sheet name instead of the codename, but I get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the statement

```
Worksheets("sheet12").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = l
```

the only thing likely to cause a "subscript out of range" error is if you don't have a worksheet with a `Name` of "sheet12".

Considering that you have a `With Sheet2` statement, it seems likely that "Sheet12" is actually the `CodeName` of your sheet, so your statement should be:

```
sheet12.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = l
```

---

However, as pointed out in comments by @Lowpar, it is better to use `End(xlUp)` when trying to find the last used row in a column, so that would be better written as:

```
sheet12.Range("B" & sheet12.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = l
```